# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "02/10/2015"

Tags: java, jfreechart

i try to convert date like 02/10/2015 to string

i am trying but i get error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "02/10/2015"
```

this is my code

```
private Crosshair xCrosshair;
long time = ds.getX(xy.getSeriesIndex(),  xy.getItem()).longValue();
        DecimalFormat dfT   = new DecimalFormat("00");
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        long lDte = (long)time;
        Date dtXX = new Date(lDte);
        gc.setTime(dtXX);
        String sDD  = dfT.format(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))));
        String sMM  = dfT.format(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)+1)));
        String sYY  = dfT.format(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(gc.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR))));
        String dateString = sDD +"/"+ sMM +"/"+ sYY;
        this.xCrosshair.setValue(Double.parseDouble(dateString));
```

Comment: What double should `02/10/2015` represent?

Comment: because xCrosshair take double only

Answer (score 2):

This row

```
this.xCrosshair.setValue(Double.parseDouble(dateString));
```

try to convert a String that is a date to a Double (that is not a date)

Comment: whats solution u see ?

Comment: What you need to do exactly? If crosshair receive a double wich value you like to pass to it? Is not clear from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You code cannot work:

```
String dateString = sDD +"/"+ sMM +"/"+ sYY;
this.xCrosshair.setValue(Double.parseDouble(dateString));
```

dateString will always have a `/` so it never will be correctly parsed.

For this use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
long d = dt.parse(dateString).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the error is happening because you are trying to parse a string that contains invalid characters, see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

If you want to parse the date as a double, then one possible solution would be:

```
String doubleString = sDD + sMM + sYY; // Simply leave the slashes out, but is this really what you're after?
this.xCrosshair.setValue(Double.parseDouble(doubleString));
```